# adding a rule to set single digit condition in a loop

Tags: jquery, loops, if-statement, setinterval

I have a function which loops through 28 images.

The first images are `1234jd01.jpg` and then `1234jd02.jpg` all the way to `09.jpg`

After the loop has gone from `01` to `09` it should go to `10`, `12` and all the way up `28` and then loop back.

However my code just does `1,2,4 - 9` and then `10, 11` which works.

**Can I add a `0` to the first set if it is a single digit and then stop at 28? So the first block of images is not showing as missing?**

jsFiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/khaleelm/Vv2u3/2/

My code is

```
$(function () {
    var i = 01;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        jQuery('.animationMax img').attr({
            src: 'http://jdsports.scene7.com/is/image/JDSports/127932jd' + i + '?hei=255&amp;wid=427&amp;resmode=sharp&amp;op_usm=1.1,0.5,0,0&amp;defaultImage=JDSports/sizeImageMissing'
        });
        i++;
        if (i === 28) i = 01; //38 images has been shown, stop the interval
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: why is this question tagged as akamai?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..........

**Code:**

```
$(function () {
    var i = 1;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        jQuery('.animationMax img').attr({
            src: 'http://jdsports.scene7.com/is/image/JDSports/127932jd'+('0'+i).slice(-2)+ '?hei=255&amp;wid=427&amp;resmode=sharp&amp;op_usm=1.1,0.5,0,0&amp;defaultImage=JDSports/sizeImageMissing'
        });
        i++;
        if (i === 28) i = 1; //38 images has been shown, stop the interval
    }, 100); });
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE......................................................................](http://jsfiddle.net/Vv2u3/4/)

Comment: Also please note this ties into a bigger question if you fancy answering it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745790/how-can-i-call-clearinterval-outside-of-a-function-in-jquery-outside-the-setint?noredirect=1#comment31086400_20745790

Comment: May I request you to please [vote to undelete this question please](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48831106/548225)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    var i = "01";
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        jQuery('.animationMax img').attr({
            src: 'http://jdsports.scene7.com/is/image/JDSports/127932jd' + i + '?hei=255&amp;wid=427&amp;resmode=sharp&amp;op_usm=1.1,0.5,0,0&amp;defaultImage=JDSports/sizeImageMissing'
        });
        i++;
        i = ('0' + i).slice(-2);
        if (i == 28) i = "01"; //38 images has been shown, stop the interval
    }, 100);
});
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Vv2u3/3/)

Comment: Thanks. I added some rep for you. Also please note this ties into a bigger question if you fancy answering it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745790/how-can-i-call-clearinterval-outside-of-a-function-in-jquery-outside-the-setint?noredirect=1#comment31086400_20745790