# How can I call clearInterval outside of a function in jQuery? Outside the setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, setinterval, clearinterval

```
    function iPadMovie(id) {
    $(function () {
        var i = 1;
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            jQuery('.animationMax img').attr({
                src: 'http://jdsports.scene7.com/is/image/JDSports/127932jd' + ('0' + i).slice(-2) + '?hei=255&amp;wid=427&amp;resmode=sharp&amp;op_usm=1.1,0.5,0,0&amp;defaultImage=JDSports/sizeImageMissing'
            });
            i++;
            if (i === 28) i = 1;
        }, 100);
    });
}

function playIpad(){
    iPadMovie();
}


function stopIpad(){
    clearInterval = interval;
}
```

You can see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Vv2u3/15/ I want to be able to stop the movie and restart it if they press play. Surely I can use clearInterval outside the method?

Comment: Try calling the function instead of overwriting it ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak can you show example?

Comment: Your `interval` variable is scoped to the anonymous function passed to jQuery's DOM ready handler, so won't be visible in the `stopIpad()` function. After you've fixed that, it's just: `clearInterval(interval)` rather than `clearInterval = interval`.

Comment: define interval variable on the outerscope (global???)

Comment: `clearInterval(interval)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Vv2u3/16/).

```
var interval;

function iPadMovie(id) {
    $(function () {
        var i = 1;
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            jQuery('.animationMax img').attr({
                src: 'http://jdsports.scene7.com/is/image/JDSports/127932jd' + ('0' + i).slice(-2) + '?hei=255&amp;wid=427&amp;resmode=sharp&amp;op_usm=1.1,0.5,0,0&amp;defaultImage=JDSports/sizeImageMissing'
            });
            i++;
            if (i === 28) i = 1;
        }, 100);
    });
}

function playIpad(){
    iPadMovie();
}
```

Little bit explanation here. 
First of all, your interval variable, (which is actual handler for returned callback function by setInterval) is not visible outside of `iPadMovie()` function so interval variable should be declared outside of this function.
Second you should call `clearInterval(handler)` function inside of `stopIpad()` function. More information can be founded [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval).

```
function stopIpad(){
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`clearInterval` is a function. You should call it, passing it the interval you want to clear as the only argument:

```
function stopIpad(){
    clearIntervar(interval);
}
```

This part is almost correct, `interval` is a variable where you remember the interval handle that you want to clear:

```
var interval = setInterval(...);
```

However, the `interval` variable needs to be declared outside the `iPadMovie` function so that it's visible to the `stopIpad` function. Move the `var` statement outside.

Also, what happens if the play button is pressed twice? You could stop the current interval before you set a new one:

```
var interval;
function iPadMovie(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(...);
}
```

As a side note, is there a reason why the `iPadMovie` waits for document ready? I would expect it to only be called after that point. If this is the case, you can remove the `$(function(){...})` wrapper.