# javascript Split string and keep separator as own array value

Tags: javascript, regex

I have strings which are just basic math equations. How can I split each number into an array and leave the operator as its own item in the array?

```
"123/12*312+4-2"
```

The output I would like to have is the following:

```
["123", "/", "12", "*", "312", "+", "4", "-", "2"]
```

I am using this:

```
str.split(/[^\d]/)
```

All other ways of doing this keep the separator but it is part of the number instead of its own array value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use a capture group in regex:

```js
var str = "123/12*312+4-2";
var arr = str.split(/(\D)/);

console.log(arr)
```

`\D` is same as `[^\d]` (anything but digits)

Comment: This adds the separator as another value in the array and doesn't keep it in the first value

Comment: Please check OP's expected output, that is what OP wanted.

Comment: Could you kindly add an extension for this issue? For future reference on google for people like me :-)

Comment: Use `var arr = str.match(/\d+(?:\D+|$)/g);`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method.

```js
console.log(
  "123/12*312+4-2".match(/\d+|\D/g)
)
```

In regex, `\d+` for number combination and `\D` for non digit.